# Angular post file to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post

Hello here's my json "names" :

```
[
    {
        "file": "file1.zip",
        "date": "12-03-2016",
    },
    {
        "file": "file2.zip",
        "date": "24-06-2016",
    },
    {
        "file": "file3.zip",
        "date": "02-12-2016",
    }]
```

My javascript file:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.service('service', function($http, $q){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('newapi.json').then(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

        this.getNames = function(){
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    });
    app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service){
        var promise = service.getNames();
        promise.then(function(data){
            $scope.names = data.data;
            $scope.namesplit = $scope.names;
            $scope.namesplit.map(function(item) {
                item.time = new Date(item.date * 1000);
            });
            console.log($scope.namesplit);
        });
        });
```

and HTML :

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in names">
   <td>{{name.file}}</td>
   <td>{{name.date}}</td>
   <td><button>POST</button></td>
</tr>
```

What i need to do is create method $http.post, which on click button "POST", post "file" to serwer. How to do this in controller?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with something like `$upload` which send to the server a file ... something like:

```
 <!--UPLOAD-->
                                <div class="up-buttons">

                                    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center box-upload-image" data-ng-show="profileCtrl.uploadImage">
                                        <br />
                                        <div id="imgDragDrop" ng-file-drop ng-model="files"
                                             drag-over-class="dragover"
                                             accept="image/*">

                                            <div class="cropArea-bkg">
                                                <h4>
                                                    <span class="mdi mdi-account mdi-48px"></span>
                                                    <br /><br />
                                                    Carica immagine profilo
                                                </h4>

                                                <p>Trascina qui la tua immagine, oppure</p>

                                                <div ng-file-select="" ng-model="files" class="btn btn-secondary" ng-accept="'*.pdf,*.jpg,*.png'" tabindex="0">
                                                    Sfoglia sul tuo computer
                                                </div><br>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div ng-no-file-drop class="well bg-danger">File Drag/Drop non supported by this browser</div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                            <div class="progress" ng-show="uploading">
                                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ ::progress }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{::progress}}% ">
                                                    <span class="sr-only">{{ ::progress }}% Complete</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <!--END UPLOAD-->

                                </div>
```

And the js in your Controller ..maybe to call in a click button function

```
    //Upload Func

$scope.clickBtn = function(){
                $scope.upload = function (files) {
                    if (files && files.length) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                            var file = files[i];
                            $scope.uploading = true;
                            //   $scope.imageName = file.name;
                            $upload.upload({
                                url: enviroment.apiUrl + '/api/CurrentUser/Profile/Image',
                                //fields: { 'username': $scope.username },
                                file: file
                            }).progress(function (evt) {
                                $scope.uploading = true;
                                var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                                console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
                                $scope.progress = progressPercentage;
                            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + data);
                                $scope.imageName = data;
                                $scope.uploading = false;
                                $scope.loadSuccess = true;
                                vm.uploadImage = false;
                                //AR
                                var reader = new FileReader();
                                reader.onload = function (evt) {
                                    $scope.$apply(function ($scope) {
                                        $scope.myImage = evt.currentTarget.result;
                                    });
                                };
                                reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
                                //END AR
                            });
                        }
                    }
                };
}



  // Stay on Listen upload file
            $scope.$watch('files', function (evt) {
                $scope.upload($scope.files);
            });
```